# Create a function with parameters using CTE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am newly working with oracle SQL and I have the following problem message:
Errors: FUNCTION FN_CHEAPESTCOMPUTER
Line/Col: 2/32 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ) , @ % default character
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Line/Col: 6/6 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "X" when expecting one of the following:

follow my code bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_cheapestComputer 
(speed int, ram int, hd varchar(10))
RETURN int
AS
BEGIN
WITH x AS
    (
    SELECT model, price, serial_number, speed, ram, hd
    FROM pc
    UNION
    SELECT model, price, serial_number, speed, ram, hd
    FROM laptop
    )
    SELECT pr.type, pr.maker, x.serial_number, x.speed, x.ram, x.hd, x.price
    FROM x
        left join product pr on pr.model = x.model
    WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM x)
    GROUP BY type, maker, serial_number, speed, ram, hd, price;
RETURN;
END;
```

also, follow the tables that I use:

[image]

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting the use of a function. A function needs to give something back to the caller.  So if your query returns 1 row (or 10 rows) etc ... what do you want to *do* with those rows? What does the caller of the function want back? The rows? Something else?

Comment: No idea the syntax for table functions in Oracle, but that query doesn't look very efficient. Firstly, you probably don't need `UNION` (de-duplication) just `UNION ALL`. Secondly, the `price` subquery would be far more efficient if was a rownumber solution instead

Comment: also you are missing a comma after laptop)

Comment: And you don't specify the length of a `varchar2` column when you're setting up a parameter.